# ALTER ROLE DROP MEMBER succeeds but doesn't drop member

Tags: sql-server, role

So this one has me stumped. We're doing some permissions cleanup and we have some AD groups we'd like to remove from a database role.

We run `ALTER ROLE MyRole DROP MEMBER [domain\group]` and get `Commands completed successfully.`.

BUT

the group is still a member of the role.

Any ideas? The login running the commands is a sysadmin on the instance. We've also tried the old `exec sp_droprolemember` with the same result.

Comment: How are you determining the user is still a role member? Perhaps you need to refresh SSMS OE.

Comment: The member still shows in SSMS and in a query of sys.database_role_members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `domain\user` is a **Windows group member**, and that Windows group is the member of the role from which you want to remove your user.

I show you an example:

My domain account `BL-DB-COLL2\dev4` is member of Windows group `BL-DB-COLL2\TestGroup` and `BL-DB-COLL2\TestGroup` is member of `db_datareader` fixed server role, I can see this by querying `sys.database_role_members` or you can see it in Object Explorer under Roles if you click the role of your interest. You'll see Windows group as a member, not a single Windows account.

In my example Windows group `BL-DB-COLL2\TestGroup` is member of `db_datareader`:

[image]

Now if I execute `ALTER ROLE db_datareader DROP MEMBER [BL-DB-COLL2\dev4]` I also have `Commands completed successfully.` but my user is still there

[image]

To remove your user from database role you either remove the whole **Windows group** from the role or remove domain account from that Windows group, I don't think it's a good idea to do the first and in my simple case I just executed `deny select to [BL-DB-COLL2\dev4]` and this user can no more do any `SELECT`, even if it is still a member of db_datareader.

The correct way to complete this is "administrative" way: you should ask you HR responsible to move this person into another team that has other tasks to do and belongs to other Windows group. Once the user is removed from this Windows group at Windows level and put in another Windows group with limited permissions that this group should have you've done your work, otherwise you manually deny all the permissions that the role has to this `domain\user`. Note that in this case it will be difficult to someone else to guess how it is possible that "db_datareader member cannot do any SELECT".

Comment: Actually, the member is an AD group already. Will the same thing happen if the group is a member of another group that is also a member?

Comment: @Spivonious originally your question was about **domain\user** , member of Windows group. But the same thing happens when one Windows group is member of another Windows group, you should find out the "outer" group that is member of database role, until that group is a member of db role your DROP MEMBER will not take any effect, so the same thing: you can DENY to the "inner" group the permissions you don't want them to have or you should ask you Windows administrator  to remove that "inner" group from "outer" group, then map it on sql server and give it only permissions you want

Comment: Thanks! It was the double membership causing the dropped member to remain.